# Issue in R 'x' must be atomic"

Tags: r

Here is my code from the package phytools in R, I am trying to run a summary of my simtrees which must be in the class phylo or multiphylo but when I run the code below I get this error.

```
class(YY)<-"multiPhylo"
class(YY)
[1] "multiPhylo"
describe.simmap(YY)

YY <- describe.simmap(simtrees, plot=F)
 Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
    'x' must be atomic
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is your question reproducible? It really helps to answer a question if the data and code can be easily copied to repeat the problem then test and verify a solution.

Comment: Making an arbitrary object a specific `class` does not at all ensure that the object is structured in a way that the package expects it to be. `a <- 1; class(a) <- "multiPhylo"` initially works, but it isn't at all meaningful. How did you generate `YY`? Why do you feel you must (and *can*) assign a class to it that is not already assigned?